# GCP Delete Compute Engine - VM Instances - without enabling the billing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-billing

I have a situation to delete lot of VMs which was created in my GCP Project. But I need to delete all those VMs before I enable the billing.

Is this possible?

I tried with Cloud Shell, but No luck as the VM are Delete protection enabled.

Comment: Log into the Google Cloud Console and remove the delete protection flag.

Comment: You can't create VMs in GCP without billing (at least now a days). So, what do you mean by "delete all VMs before billing".

For latter, you can use cloud shell with `gcloud compute instances update <instance-name> --no-deletion-protection` in a for loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the Cloud Console, Cloud Shell or GCP API to disable the Delete Protection first.

For Cloud Console, just go to Compute Engine > VM Instance > Click the instance to be edited > Click Edit > Uncheck "Enable Deletion Protection".

But for multiple VM's it is advisable to use the cloud shell instead. See the template below:

> gcloud compute instances update [INSTANCE_NAME] 
> [--deletion-protection | --no-deletion-protection]

For example:

> gcloud compute instances update vm-instance1 --no-deletion-protection

For more information about this topic, you can check this link. [Toggling deletion protection](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/preventing-accidental-vm-deletion#toggling_deletion_protection_for_existing_instances)